# Running Perl script on Linux with ForkManager

Tags: linux, perl, centos, vps

I am trying to run Perl script on my vps serer that it gets the Ip title of `text-file` where `text-file` is a list of ips.
but i am getting this error :

```
 Use of uninitialized value $args[0] in pattern match (m//) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Parallel/ForkManager.pm line 73.
Missing required arguments: max_proc at ./get line 12.
```

where line 73 is `if ( $args[0] =~ /^\d+$/ ) {`
and line 12 is `my $forkmanager = new Parallel::ForkManager->new("200");`

my question is about how get this error fixed ?
any help please

Comment: Can you please show us a short, self-contained program that reproduces the error? It's hard to guess what could be causing this without seeing the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

No way for us to know what `$args[0]` contains (or doesn't contain). Please provide a full code snippet where the error is reproducible.

As for the ForkManager error: First, try instantiating the ForkManager object with its newer Moose-style arguments, ie. `my $forkmanager = Parallel::ForkManager->new(max_procs => 200);`

Also note that using the `new` keyword is discouraged. From [perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html):

> Outside of the file handle case, use of this syntax is discouraged as it can confuse the Perl interpreter. See below for more details.

Comment: the file forkmanager.pm is too long
maybe this code can help in declare the problem
` if ( $args[0] =~ /^\d+$/ ) {
        $args{max_proc} = shift @args;
        $args{tempdir} = shift @args if @args;
    }
    else {
        %args = @args;
    }

    return \%args;
}`